# MUI data table row selection checkbox opacity issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

In MUI Data Table I'm using first column as checkboxes as sticky.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHuAb.png)

when I scroll horizontal to left the data is overflowing need to fix this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMpnM.png)

Please find below code
Table component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './customtable.css';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import {
  TableContainer,
  Table,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  TableCell,
  TableBody,
  Checkbox,
  IconButton,
  Button,
  Paper,
  TablePagination,
  Switch,
  FormGroup,
  FormControlLabel,
} from '@mui/material';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import { CSVLink } from 'react-csv';
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import 'jspdf-autotable';
import image from '../../assets/images/Excel.png';
import pdf from '../../assets/images/pdf.png';
import { TextDecrease } from '@mui/icons-material';
import MUIDataTable from 'mui-datatables';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

const getMuiTheme = () =>
  createTheme({
    components: {
      MUIDataTableToolbar: {
        styleOverrides: {
          root: {
            minHeight: '50px',
            display: 'flex',
          },
          actions: {
            display: 'flex',
            flex: 'inherit',
          },
        },
      },
      MUIDataTableBodyCell: {
        styleOverrides: {
          // padding: '10px',
          root: {
            border: 'none',
            padding: 'none',
            fontSize: '12px',
            fontFamily: 'helvetica !important',
            opacity:1,
          },
          simpleHeader: {
            // padding: '10px',
          },
          simpleCell: {
            // padding: '10px',
          },
          stackedHeader: {
            verticalAlign: 'top',
          },
          stackedCommon: {
            // padding: '10px',
          },
          stackedCommonAlways: {
            // padding: '10px',
          },
          stackedParent: {
            // padding: '10px',
          },
          stackedParentAlways: {
            // padding: '10px',
          },
          cellStackedSmall: {
            // padding: '10px',
          },
          responsiveStackedSmall: {
            // padding: '10px',
          },
          responsiveStackedSmallParent: {
            // padding: '10px',
          },
        },
      },
      MUIDataTableSelectCell: {
        styleOverrides: {
          root: {
            opacity:1,
            borderBottom: 'none',
          },

          headerCell: {
            borderBottom: '1px solid #d9d9d9',
          },
        },
      },
      MUIDataTableHeadCell: {
        styleOverrides: {
          root: {
            // borderBottom: 'none !important',
            opacity:1,
            borderTop: '1px solid #d9d9d9',
            fontSize: '14px !important',
            fontFamily: 'helvetica !important',
            fontWeight: 'bold !important',
            padding: '10px 16px 10px 16px',
            // borderRight: 'none',
          },
          toolButton: {
            fontSize: '14px !important',
            fontFamily: 'helvetica !important',
            fontWeight: 'bold !important',
          },
        },
      },
      MUIDataTableHeadRow: {
        styleOverrides: {
          root: {
            opacity:1,
            // borderBottom: 'none !important',
            borderTop: '1px solid #d9d9d9',
            fontSize: '14px !important',
            fontFamily: 'helvetica !important',
            fontWeight: 'bold !important',
            // borderRight: 'none',
          },
        },
      },
      MUIDataTableFooter: {
        styleOverrides: {
          root: {
            opacity:1,
            borderTop: 'solid 1px #dee2e6',
          },
        },
      },
      MuiTableCell: {
        styleOverrides: {
          root: {
            zIndex:1,
            opacity:1,
            color: "#000000"
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    fontSize: '12px',
    fontWeight: 400,
    fontStyle: 'helvetica',
    textAlign: 'center',
    opacity:1
  },
  container: {
    opacity:1,
    zIndex:1 

  },
});

const AntSwitch = styled(Switch)(({ theme }) => ({
  width: 28,
  height: 16,
  padding: 0,
  marginRight: 5,
  display: 'flex',
  '&:active': {
    '& .MuiSwitch-thumb': {
      width: 15,
    },
    '& .MuiSwitch-switchBase.Mui-checked': {
      transform: 'translateX(9px)',
    },
  },
  '& .MuiSwitch-switchBase': {
    padding: 2,
    '&.Mui-checked': {
      transform: 'translateX(12px)',
      color: '#fff',
      opacity:1,
      '& + .MuiSwitch-track': {
        opacity: 1,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#177ddc' : '#9D1D27',
      },
    },
  },
  '& .MuiSwitch-thumb': {
    boxShadow: '0 2px 4px 0 rgb(0 35 11 / 20%)',
    width: 12,
    height: 12,
    borderRadius: 6,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width'], {
      duration: 200,
    }),
  },
  '& .MuiSwitch-track': {
    borderRadius: 16 / 2,
    opacity: 1,
    backgroundColor:
      theme.palette.mode === 'dark'
        ? 'rgba(255,255,255,.35)'
        : 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)',
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
  },
}));

const CustomTable = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const {
    data,
    columns,
    docTitle,
    isReports,
    handleShowMoreColumns,
    showMoreColumns,
  } = props;
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0); // add state for current page
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(5); // add state for rows per page
  const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
  }, [selectedRows]);
  const handleSelectAllClick = (event) => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      const newSelectedRows = data.map((row) => row.id);
      setSelectedRows(newSelectedRows);
    } else {
      setSelectedRows([]);
    }
  };
  const handleClick = (event, rowId) => {
    const selectedIndex = selectedRows.indexOf(rowId);
    let newSelectedRows = [];

    if (selectedIndex === -1) {
      newSelectedRows = [...selectedRows, rowId];
    } else if (selectedIndex > -1) {
      newSelectedRows = [
        ...selectedRows.slice(0, selectedIndex),
        ...selectedRows.slice(selectedIndex + 1),
      ];
    }

    setSelectedRows(newSelectedRows);
  };

  const isSelected = (rowId) => selectedRows.indexOf(rowId) !== -1;
  const selectedData = data.filter((row, index) =>
    selectedRows.includes(index)
  );
  const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
    // function to handle page changes
    setPage(newPage);
  };

  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
    // function to handle rows per page changes
    setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
    setPage(0);
  };
  

  const handleExportPDF = () => {
    const unit = 'pt';
    const pageSize = jsPDF.getPageSize('landscape', 'pt');
    const orientation = 'landscape';
    const marginLeft = 40;
    const doc = new jsPDF(orientation, unit, [pageSize.width, pageSize.height]);

    const headers = columns.map((column) => column.label);
    const data = [];
    selectedData.forEach((row) => {
      const rowData = [];
      columns.forEach((column) => {
        rowData.push(row[column.name]);
      });
      data.push(rowData);
    });

    let totalPages = 1;

    const content = {
      startY: 50,
      head: [headers],
      body: data,
      didParseCell: function (data) {
        data.cell.styles.cellPadding = 5;
        data.cell.styles.fontSize = 10;
        data.cell.styles.overflow = 'linebreak';
        data.cell.styles.cellHeight = 'auto';
      },
      columnStyles: {
        // Set the width of each column here
        // For example, this sets the width of the first column to 80pt
        0: { cellWidth: 80 },
      },
      // Add a hook to check the height of the table on each page
      didDrawPage: function (data) {
        const { settings, table } = data;
        const height = table.height + settings.margin.top;
        if (totalPages === 1 && height > pageSize.height / 2) {
          // Set the startY position to half the page height
          content.startY = pageSize.height / 2;
          // Add a new page and continue the table
          doc.addPage();
          // Increment the total page count
          totalPages++;
          // Draw the table again from the start row
          this.startRowIndex = 0;
          this.drawTable({ startRowIndex: this.startRowIndex });
        } else if (totalPages > 1) {
          // Increment the total page count
          totalPages++;
          // Draw the table again from the start row
          this.startRowIndex = 0;
          this.drawTable({ startRowIndex: this.startRowIndex });
        }
      },
    };

    doc.text(docTitle || 'Report', marginLeft, 40);
    doc.autoTable(content);

    doc.save(fileNamePdf);
  };

  const headers = columns.map((column) => {
    return { label: column.label, name: column.name, key: column.name };
  });

  const options = {
    filter: true,
    resizableColumns: false,
    print: false,
    download: false,
    rowHover: false,
    pagination: true,
    selectableRowsHeader: true,
    // tableBodyHeight:'320px',
    tableBodyMaxHeight: '320px',
    selectableRows: 'multiple',
    rowsPerPage: 5,
    rowsPerPageOptions: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100],
    filterType: 'textFiled',
    responsive: 'vertical',
    onRowSelectionChange: (rowsSelectedData, allRows, rowsSelected) => {
      setSelectedRows(rowsSelected);
    },
    selectToolbarPlacement: 'none',
    onRowsDelete: (rowsDeleted, newData) => {
      return false;
    },
    customToolbar: () => {
      return (
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'end' }}>
          
        
         

          <Button
            // variant="contained"
            // color="primary"
            type="button"
            style={{
              float: 'right',
              borderRadius: '12px',
              paddingTop: '3px',
              paddingBottom: '3px',
            }}
          >
            {/* Export */}
            <CSVLink
              data={selectedData}
              headers={headers}
              filename={fileNameCSV}
            >
              <img
                src={image}
                width='30px'
                height='30px'
                style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }}
              />
            </CSVLink>
            <img
              src={pdf}
              width='20px'
              height='20px'
              onClick={handleExportPDF}
              style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }}
            />
          </Button>
        </div>
      );
    },
  };

  let fileDateTime = new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10);
  let fileName = 'Report_' + fileDateTime; //+".csv";
  let fileNameCSV = fileName + '.csv';
  let fileNamePdf = fileName + '.pdf';

  return (
    <Paper className={classes.root}>
      
      <TableContainer className={classes.container}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={getMuiTheme()}>
          <MUIDataTable className={classes.container}
            // title='Search Results'
            // components={{
            //   TableFooter: CustomFilterList,
            // }}
            data={data}
            columns={headers}
            options={options}
            // components={components}
          />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </TableContainer>
    </Paper>
  );
};
export default CustomTable;
```

I don't want to see data overflows inside checkboxes when I scroll horizontal left.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).